# Face detection using OpenCV : application crashes using CGContextDrawImage ( EXC_BAD_ACCESS )

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm using OpenCV in my swift project to detect faces on pictures from an iPhone's gallery.

When I try to process a UIImage picked from the gallery, I'm first doing that :

```
+ (UIImage *)processImageWithOpenCV:(UIImage*)inputImage {
    ...
    cv::Mat img = [inputImage CVGrayscaleMat];
    ...
}
```

Here is my CVGrayscaleMat method :

```
-(cv::Mat)CVGrayscaleMat
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGFloat cols = self.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = self.size.height;

    cv::Mat cvMat((int)rows, (int)cols, CV_8UC1); // 8 bits per component, 1 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to data
                                                    (int)cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                    (int)rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    4896,              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNone |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, (int)cols, (int)rows), self.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return cvMat;
}
```

When I try to process a picture, I got a  ***EXC_BAD_ACCESS*** on that line :

```
CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, (int)cols, (int)rows), self.CGImage);
```

I'm still not super familiar with OpenCV... Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

**SOLVED :**

Using the standard function [- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html)

Comment: can't you use the standard function [cvMatGrayFromUIImage](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html)?

Comment: It actually worked with the standard function - (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image from your link.
Thanks !